# How to enable https for a dev environment on Angular app

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, https

I have created a website using angular that I am hosting on AWS EC2. I have done some research into how to get my server to be secure with https, and it looks like here are my options:

1. use angular, add https into angular app
2. use AWS, use load balancers and use https listener

However, I am new to both AWS and Angular and don't really know where to go from here. My web server is run on Ubuntu, and the 2 tutorials on AWS are for Windows or Linux. Any resources/suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Angular provides the way to run your website on SSL

```
ng serve --ssl
```

Also, you can add SSL cert path in the angular.json file:

```
{
   "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
   "projects": {
       "<PROJECT-NAME>": {
           "architect": {
               "serve: {
                   "options": {
                       "sslKey": "<relative path from angular.json>/server.key",
                       "sslCert": "<relative path from angular.json>/server.crt",
                       ...
                   }, ...
               }, ...
           }, ...
       }, ...
   }, ...
}
```

you can setup load balancer on EC2 instance using this guide:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-create-https-ssl-load-balancer.html

Comment: That's not correct, the https you mentioned is for local development, he meant production build on https

Comment: I think he asked how to enable https on dev env - as the title says - How to enable https for a dev environment on Angular app - nothing is mentioned for production build

Comment:  true,  question is misleading. Well what I understood is that he has an Angular app that is ready for deploying to DEV environment and he wants to use https for it. `ng serve ` is only for local development setup.

Comment: Yes, kind of. But he just wanted to enable it on dev, angular provides a way to achieve it.

Comment: Hi, sorry if the title was misleading, the server is live on an ip address so it is already hosted. I want to get an https in front of the ip address

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to add HTTPS IMO would be installing a web server (like `NGINX` or `Apache2`) as a reverse-proxy for your application. The purpose of a web-server in this case would be to accepts requests over HTTPS and forward them with HTTP to your application. Once the application responded, a reverse proxy would pass the response back to client using HTTPS.

If you have NGINX or Apache2 you can use `certbot` to obtain and renew a certificate from letsencrypt. There are lots of guides how to setup all this on the Internet, just google for `nginx letsencrypt angular`.